# Linker Error Duplicate

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am getting a linker error for my AVL tree i created that I am trying to use in my Project.  If i take out all code related to my AVLTree.h file the error goes away, but when I include it in one of my other files, i get this linker error.  Does anyone know what causes this type of error and how to fix it?  I have been on it for an hour now and info on the internet is vague.

```
Ld /Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Products/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine normal x86_64
cd /Users/DRizzuto/Documents/School/College/Sophomore/Semester_2/CSE_2341/Search_Engine/Project/Pray4theA_SearchEngine
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc++ -o /Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Products/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine

duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree6insertEP10StemObjectRP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree8bsheightEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3srlERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3drlERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3srrERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3drrERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3maxEii in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree4findEPcRP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree9makeemptyERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree8preorderEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree7inorderEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree9postorderEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree7nonodesEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DocumentParser.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree6insertEP10StemObjectRP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree8bsheightEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3srlERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3drlERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3srrERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3drrERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3maxEii in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree4findEPcRP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree9makeemptyERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree8preorderEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree7inorderEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree9postorderEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree7nonodesEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StressTest.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree6insertEP10StemObjectRP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree8bsheightEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3srlERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3drlERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3srrERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3drrERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree3maxEii in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree4findEPcRP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree9makeemptyERP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree8preorderEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree7inorderEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree9postorderEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7AVLTree7nonodesEP4node in:
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/DRizzuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pray4theA_SearchEngine-ddqogmeidbenmlefgoskzfkivrml/Build/Intermediates/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Debug/Pray4theA_SearchEngine.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UserInterface.o
ld: 39 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Most likely you are *defining* your class functions in the header file, but not as inline functions. Either make them `inline` or put the definitions in a separate source file that you link with the project.

Comment: Can you give me a little more info on what your talking about, i dont quite follow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a lot of symbols defined in both `DocumentParser.cpp` and `main.cpp` (or .cxx or .cc)

This usually means that, for example, `__ZN7AVLTree3srrERP4node` is **defined** directly in both files, or indirectly in both files via an include. You can have as many declarations of a symbol as you want, but only one definition.

Is `__ZN7AVLTree3srrERP4node` defined in a header? If so, is it marked as `extern`?

Comment: I only have one extern variable, and it is a char * that is assigned to an command line argument.  Other than that I do not have any extern variables.  My AVLTree.h file (which is where Node is located) does not use this extern object though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have e.g. a header file that looks like

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
public:
    void Somefunction();
};

void Foo::SomeFunction()
{
    // Do stuff
}

#endif
```

Then the member function `Foo::SomeFunction` is *defined* in the header file (and all sources the header file is included in).

Instead put the function definitions in a separate source file that you build with the project.

So you have the header file:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
public:
    void Somefunction();
};

#endif
```

And a source file:

```
#include "foo.h"

void Foo::SomeFunction()
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

---

You can also make the function *inline*, either by defining them inside the class, like

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
public:
    void Somefunction()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
};

#endif
```

Or by using the `inline` keyword:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
public:
    void Somefunction();
};

inline void Foo::SomeFunction()
{
    // Do stuff
}

#endif
```

Comment: Can you expand on this a little, I dont quite understand

Comment: @user3525456 Put the function implementations in a source file, not in the header file.

Comment: I tried the inline thing and it did not work, i still get a linker error, however it is comparible shorter